# Or symbol for JavaScript object declaration

Tags: javascript

I just started to read some JavaScript project. Most of the .js file to start with have an object declared as the following:

```
window.Example || {
bleh: "123";
blah: "ref"
}
```

What does the `||` symbol do here?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. But this has been asked a thousand times before on SO.

Comment: be careful when using this technique if your `window.Example` property can be 0, empty string, false, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects in Javascript are truthy, so that expression evaluates to either `window.Example` or the default object if `window.Example` is falsy (or undefined). Example:

```
var x = window.Example || {foo: 'bar'};
// x = {foo: 'bar'}, since window.Example is undefined

window.Example = {test: 1};

var y = window.Example || {foo: 'bar'};
// y = {test: 1}, since window.Example is truthy (all objects are truthy)
```

Read [this article](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript/) for a good explanation on truthy/falsy and short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @user1240679 Thanks for letting me know! It required a trailing forward slash haha. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

The `||` operator in JavaScript is *like* the "or" operator in other C-like languages, but it's distinctly different. It really means:

1. Evaluate the subexpresson to the left.
2. If that value, when coerced to boolean, is `true`, then that subexpression's value (*before* coercion to boolean) is the value of the `||` expression
3. Else evaluate the right-hand subexpression and yield its value as the value of the `||` expression.

Thus it's used idiomatically to initialize something that might already be initialized:

```
var something = window.something || defaultValue;
```

just means, "check to see if "something" is a property of the `window` object with a truthy value, and if it's not, then set it to defaultValue."

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks for fixing my typos :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's an important bit missing from that code - the variable declaration:

```
var something = window.Example || {
    bleh: "123",
    blah: "ref"
}
```

This roughly translates to "set `something` to `window.Example`, unless it doesn't exist, then set it to this new object".